# Strange rotations values, i rotate z axis, in side bar all x,y,z values change?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to rotate an object in global using the hotkeys rotate-z, I expected it to only affect the Z axis rotation values yet its modifying all rotational values almost as if its using local? Am I doing something wrong?
ive tried applying rotational values, changing origin point but still persists
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i'm sorry I can't. its for work, thats why its just a couple basic pieces thats visable

Comment: You could just share the piece itself

Comment: Is the object the child of a skew parent?

Comment: Ah yes Robin it was! thank you!